# trigger localNotification only when user enters a specified region

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification, region-monitoring

This is my code for the `didEnterRegion` function. Problem is that the notification triggers while entering as well as exiting. What can I do to trigger the notification only when the user enters the location ?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {
        var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.alertBody = "you've entered rohini sector -8"
        localNotification.region = region
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
        NSLog("Entering region")
    }
```

Comment: Why are you specifying the region in the local notification?  You already know that they are in the region since you got a call to `didEnterRegion` so specifying the region on the notification is redundant

Comment: @Paulw11 thanx man. dont know how i missed this. Works flawlessly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the region in the local notification.  You already know that the device is inside the region, because you had a call to `didEnterRegion` - specifying the region on the notification is redundant - You can simply post the notification without the region specified.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying wether you want to monitor entering or exiting the region.  When you create your region you set notifyOnExit or notifyOnEntry . If you only want exit then make that value true and the other false... or if only entry.. do the opposite

```
///// snipped taken from ray wenderlichs code...

// 1
let region = CLCircularRegion(center: geotification.coordinate,
    radius: geotification.radius, identifier: geotification.identifier)

// 2
region.notifyOnEntry = false
region.notifyOnExit = true
```